# MeanIoU calculation approaches for semantic segmentation, which one is correct?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, semantic-segmentation

I find many repositories, where MeanIoU is calculated over the complete batch. The whole batch of images are flattened and then intersection & union are calculated like below.

```
target = np.argmax(y_true, axis=-1).ravel()
predicted = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1).ravel()

# Trick for bincounting 2 arrays together
x = predicted + num_classes * target
bincount_2d = np.bincount(x.astype(np.int32), minlength=num_classes**2)
assert bincount_2d.size == num_classes**2
conf = bincount_2d.reshape((num_classes, num_classes))

# Compute the IoU and mean IoU from the confusion matrix
true_positive = np.diag(conf)
false_positive = np.sum(conf, 0) - true_positive
false_negative = np.sum(conf, 1) - true_positive

iou = true_positive / (true_positive + false_positive + false_negative)
iou[np.isnan(iou)] = 1

meaniou = np.mean(iou).astype(np.float32)
```

Instead, shall it not be calculated per image first, then averaged over all images in a batch like below,

```
target = np.argmax(y_true, axis=-1).ravel().reshape(batch_size,-1)
predict = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1).ravel().reshape(batch_size,-1)

x = predict + num_classes * target
bincount_2d = np.array([np.bincount(x[i].astype(np.int32), minlength=num_classes**2) for i in range(batch_size)])
conf = bincount_2d.reshape((-1, num_classes, num_classes))
    
true_positive = np.array([np.diag(conf[i]) for i in range(batch_size)])
false_positive = np.sum(conf, axis=1) - true_positive
false_negative = np.sum(conf, axis=2) - true_positive

iou = true_positive / (true_positive + false_positive + false_negative)
iou[np.isnan(iou)] = 1

meaniou = np.mean(iou).astype(np.float32)
```